# How to populate a list view with a title and description in each item

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database setup, which, when a button is pressed in the app, it populates a list view with the values from my database. I have it working with no problems, but I noticed in debugging that the list view had no titles. I thought I could add a new `String[]` list with all the titles, but I'm stuck on how to add to each item. This is my code for the button click:

```
 public void viewJobsOnClick(View view) {
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvday);
    final RelativeLayout Rlitem = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.joblistitemslayout);
    final RelativeLayout Rllist = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.joblistviewlayout);
   //My adapter that is populating my listview
    final ArrayAdapter<String> jlistAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, JoblistArray);

    lv.setAdapter(jlistAdapter);

    if (joblistRootRef.child("Monday").toString().contains(DAY_OF_THE_WEEK)) {
 //Firebase child listener that sends the data to my adapter
        joblistRootRef.child("Monday").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                String jlist = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Rlitem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Rllist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                JoblistArray.add(jlist);

            }
```

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Answer (score 0):

You saving only string.class obj i think you shoude study how to save java obj (POJO) in to firebase , witch incude your listview name and you listview detail
**step 1 Make a POJO** of you java class and save into firebase , if you whant to know what is pojo [here is video you can watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GDpv1XvqBA)

2nd **Use firebaseListadupter** in you app [here is link to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=son6KAi46Qk) where you will understand how firebase listadupter work

**simple code**: how firebaseListAdupter work

```
 Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<yourapp>.firebaseio.com");
     ListAdapter adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, mRef)
     {
         protected void populateView(View view, ChatMessage chatMessage)
         {
             ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(chatMessage.getName());
             ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(chatMessage.getMessage());
         }
     };
     listView.setListAdapter(adapter);
```